# Fluxor architecture - should I share an action between features?

Tags: blazor-webassembly, fluxor

I have an effect that gets some (now) common data from the server - and this is currently in Feature 1. I now have Feature 2 that needs the same data, should I add a reducer for Feature 2 that has an action from Feature 1? Or is there a better way to do this that also minimises server calls?

Technically using the action works, but is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is recommended to limit actions to the feature for preserving the isolation and the code maintainability.